# Jsonb postgres query for column of hash of array of hashes rails active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, jsonb

I am working on a Rails 6 application with model(User) containing jsonb column like this

```
  "header": {
    "areas": [
      {
        "name": "area1",
        "annotated": true
      },
      {
        "name": "area2",
        "annotated": false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to get count of number of entries where **annotated** is **true**.
I tried this, but results are not matching:

`User.where("(header -> 'areas') @> ? ", [{annotated:true}].to_json).count`

What is wrong in this query? how should it be changed?

Comment: Why are you using a placeholder if the value is fixed? It just adds context switching between Ruby and SQL and makes the code more confusing.

Comment: Im not exactly sure of this syntax, i tried it by referring some article, kindly suggest any alternatives that will suit this case